# How can I make TAB cycle through my command complete choices when using Helm?

Tags: emacs, completion, emacs-helm

When I launch helm, I start typing in a command like `org-mo` and then I get suggestions for `org-mode` `org-mobile-pull` `org-mobile-push` `org-mode-restart` and a few other commands.

Let's say I want to get to `org-mobile-pull` right now I have to use the arrow keys to select it, but I'd rather just press the `tab` key to cycle down to it, and press `S-tab` to go back up through the list.

I tried using the configurations [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33727/how-does-spacemacs-allow-tab-completion-in-helm) but I get errors with that.

I really don't care if I'm using helm or any other launcher(?) as long as I can tab through the list.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for `helm-next-line` and `helm-previous-line`, eg.

```
(with-eval-after-load 'helm
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "TAB")       #'helm-next-line)
  (define-key helm-map (kbd "<backtab>") #'helm-previous-line))
```

By default TAB is bound to `helm-select-action` so you may want to rebind that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a cheat, but adding this to my .emacs did the trick

```
(require 'helm)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "TAB") (lookup-key helm-map (kbd "<down>")))
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<S-tab>") (lookup-key helm-map (kbd "<up>")))
```